# MediaFile.getFormatData() of newly-recorded video contains bad information

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I use Cordova (PhoneGap via Ionic) 3.x and its capture plugin to record a video from the device's camera. Upon completion of recording, I'd like to get the duration of the video for use in my application. However, when I run this test on my iPad, the MediaFileData object contains zero-ed out information. Here's a snippet:

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(
    function(files) {

        var videoFile = files[0];

        videoFile.getFormatData(function(fileData) {
            console.log('file data:' + JSON.stringify(fileData));
        });
    }
);
```

The console output is:

```
file data:{"width":0,"duration":0,"bitrate":0,"codecs":null,"height":0}
```

Is there a known bug in iOS? I didn't see anything in the caveats section of the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture/blob/master/doc/index.md#mediafiledata). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue?

Comment: c0r3yz: No I did not. I had to work around the issue by re-querying media assets after the file was done being written. Even then, a race condition can happen if it takes too long to write the file and metadata. I filed a bug with Cordova and never heard anything either.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ended up working around it on my side by using the size of the file instead of the duration.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck on this issue too.
Make sure that you have the latest version of the plugin. This was fixed here:

[CB-7117](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7117)

If you cannot update the plugin do the following:

```
var videoFile = files[0];
videoFile.localURL = videoFile.fullPath;
```

Hope it helps !